# Advice about if/else loop syntax concerning removing AD groups if not in AD group

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

So this same script that I've posted about for a week now.. I'm finally on what I hope is an easy part.  The script itself right now checks for membership in a group, if in the group create a new group using the 'Report to $manager" variable.  What I need to do now is check if a group exists like 'Report to Joe.Blow' and if Joe is not in the AllManager's security group.. delete the 'Report to' group.  This is where I'm at right now:

```
import-module activedirectory
  
#Test Function Area #

Function Get-DirectReport {
#requires -Module ActiveDirectory
 
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script will get a user's direct reports recursively from ActiveDirectory unless specified with the NoRecurse parameter.
    It also uses the user's EmployeeID attribute as a way to exclude service accounts and/or non standard accounts that are in the reporting structure.
  
.NOTES
    Name: Get-DirectReport
    Author: theSysadminChannel
    Version: 1.0
    DateCreated: 2020-Jan-28
  
.LINK
    https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-direct-reports-in-active-directory-using-powershell-recursive -  
  
.PARAMETER SamAccountName
    Specify the samaccountname (username) to see their direct reports.
  
.PARAMETER NoRecurse
    Using this option will not drill down further than one level.
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport username
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport -SamAccountName username -NoRecurse
  
.EXAMPLE
    "username" | Get-DirectReport
#>
 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
 
        [string]  $SamAccountName,
 
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
 
    BEGIN {}
 
    PROCESS {
        $UserAccount = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName
        $UserAccount | select -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object {
            $User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName, Title, EmployeeID
            if ($null -ne $User.EmployeeID) {
                if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                    Get-DirectReport $User.SamAccountName
                }
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName     = $User.SamAccountName
                    UserPrincipalName  = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName        = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager            = $UserAccount.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    END {}
 
}


$ou = "ou=test, ou=Litmos, ou=Resources, ou=Groups, ou=company, dc=domain, dc=net"
$creds = "domain.net\ben"
$server = "dc01.domain.net"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

$managers = get-adGroupMember -identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | 
    select samaccountname

#Collect 
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | 
    where {$_.name -replace 'Report to ' -in $name} | 
    select name, samaccountname

#The below loop creates 'Report To' dist groups for people found in $managers
Foreach ($manager in ($managers.SamAccountName)) { 
    # Creates  missing "Report to <manager>" groups
    if ($manager -notin (($ReportsTo.Name) -replace 'Report to ')) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
    } else {
        write-warning "Group already exists"
    }
    # Get managers direct report
    $underlings = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
    if ($underlings -ne $null) {        
        #write-host "$manager has reports"
    } else {
        write-warning "$Manager has no reports"
        Continue
    }   

    # Get manager's "report to <manager> group again to update members"
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $ou -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $underlings
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Could not locate group for $manager"
    }

    # Remove groups for users who are no longer in All Managers
    $ManagerGroup = $managers
    $ReportTogroup = get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to '"
    $groupname = "Report to $manager"

    if (-not($ReportToGroup -eq "Report to $manager")
    { Remove-ADGroup $ReportToGroup 
     } else {
     Continue }
```

I know this last bit is wrong.. I'm unable to come up with a logical flow on that part..

Comment: `if (ReportToGroup.Name -replace 'Report to ' -notin $managers.samaccountname) { Remove-ADGroup $ReportToGroup }`.

Comment: Hey Admin, Thanks for the continued help. So I ended up trying to add this into a second Foreach block:  
 `$ReportTogroup = Get-ADGroup -Searchbase $ou -Filter "Name -like 'Report to '" 
Foreach ($manager in ($manager.SamAccountName)) {
    if ($ReportToGroup.name -replace 'Report to ' -notin $managers.samaccountname) {
    {Remove-ADGroup $ReportToGroup}
    write-warning "$ReportToGroup removed"
    }
} `
And tested with a new user to the group, but the Report To folder for this test user was not removed.

Comment: You may want to try `Remove-ADGroup $ReportToGroup.SamAccountName`.

Comment: Still no bueno.. actually the console spits out 
` Remove-ADGroup $ReportToGroup.samaccountname
WARNING:  removed `
For every object in $managers. Maybe my if needs an else.

Comment: I got a bit further by changing the syntax on the $reportToGroup variable
` $ReportTogroup = Get-ADGroup -Searchbase $ou -Filter {Name -like "Report to *"} `
But it's still not 100%